# Installing VB 6 Enterprize Edition on WinXP SP2 after VS Express 2008 SP1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Can I install VB6 after installing VS 2008 Express SP1?

If it does not override VS Express 2008 SP1 registry keys then I think it is safe!

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

They are completely different product lines & will not interfere with each other, you can install them both in any order you like.

Comment: Thanks Mr Alex K. very very thanks! Now I am confirmed about that VB6 does not harms VS Express 2008 SP1 in any way!